# Submitting 2 forms on seperate pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

Im building a car valuation site as and I'm using php to pass variables from one page to another through forms using $_POST.

On a normal site this works fine but on the site in wordpress the second form goes to the 404 page.

Why is this happening and what's the solution?

Thanks in advance!

There's 3 pages -
Page 1 is a form vehicle details

```
<form id="form-1" action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="user_vrm" class="user_input" name="vrm" placeholder="Your VRM">
    <input type="text" id="user_miles" class="user_input" name="miles" placeholder="Car mileage">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" id="submit-car" name="submit">
</form>
```

Page 2 displays the details and takes user info

```
<div class="results">
<?php 
    echo
        'VRM: ' . $vrm . '<br/>' . 
        'Miles: ' . $miles;
?>
</div>    
  <div class="results">
<?php 
    echo
        'VRM: ' . $vrm . '<br/>' . 
        'Miles: ' . $miles;
?>
</div>    
  
<form id="form-2" action="page3.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="user_name" class="user_input" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
    <input type="text" id="user_email" class="user_input" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
    <input type="hidden" id="user_vrm2" class="user_input" name="vrm2" value="<?php echo $vrm?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="user_miles2" class="user_input" name="miles2" value="<?php echo $miles?>">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" id="submit-user" name="submit">
</form>
```

Page 3 displays the combined results

```
<?php 
    
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$vrm = $_POST['vrm2'];
$miles = $_POST['miles2'];
 
?>

<h1>Page 3</h1>   
  
<div class="results">
<?php 
    echo
        'VRM: ' . $vrm . '<br/>' . 
        'Miles: ' . $miles . '<br/>' . 
        'Name: ' . $name . '<br/>' . 
        'Email: ' . $email;

?>
</div>
```

Comment: _“Why is this happening”_ - because you specified a wrong URL? _“and what's the solution?”_ - a proper implementation _within_ WordPress, that does not rely on targeting specific _script files_ directly, but works within WP’s routing system to begin with …?

Comment: in wordpress I'm not setting the action as page2.php but the actual url of page2 and if I enter the same url in the browser it goes to the page no problem, just not after submitting the second form. I should have made that clear, apologies.

Is there somewhere I can look to understand wp's routing system for this?

Comment: Doesn’t change that the URL appears to be wrong to begin with, otherwise why would you get a 404. Did you generate that URL using WP functions, or did you copy&paste it? Is it an absolute URL, or a relative one (that might then resolve to a _wrong_ absolute one, based on the current path depth)?

Comment: I entered the absolute url and the process works fine for the first form. The second one goes to an error page.

Comment: So calling that URL you put into the action of the second form, when called directly via your browser address bar, “works” then? And when you say “page”, you mean actual WP pages, normal as can be - or anything that any plugins might be interfering with, or any specifically setup up routes or something like that?

Comment: Yes page 3 loads if you call the url but obviously without the values in the variables.

I'm not sure. I'm quite new to PHP as you can probably tell. I dont really have any plugins installed at the moment.